# Is S3Guard for hadoop-aws still relevant when Amazon S3 is strongly consistent?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/ claims that it is. However, when I read the docs https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html it's still recommended to use S3Guard. I believe that I'm missing something. Does it mean that S3 is not strongly consistent when using `hadoop-aws` even though Amazon claims that S3 is strongly consistent?

Comment: Regarding the EMR tag that you had, last I checked, EMR uses their own hadoop-aws package. If you are referring to open-source Hadoop, then not sure it matters, but dont think the latest AWS Java SDK is being used. Also, S3Guard adds a caching layer that direct S3 access doesn't have, which would matter for rate-limiting.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the docs have not been updated since the change to AWS S3. I believe S3 Guard is no longer needed, but as @oneCricketeer said, you may still benefit from the caching it can provide.

This Apache Jira is to update the docs to deprecate S3 Guard:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17480